# $x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+y=x^2+1$, $x>0$, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. Find $f(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function comes out to be $$ c_1\cos(\ln x)+c_2\sin(\ln x)+\frac{x^2}{5}+1$$

Someone pointed out that by putting $x=0$ in the given equation, we get 
$f(0)=1$ but it is given that $f(0)=0$
hence there are no solutions.

Is this a valid argument?

Comment: It must be $$x>0$$ see the condition above!

Comment: Is your $y$ another $f(x)$? Then yes, this argument shows that you can not give initial conditions in a singular point without restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given equation has to be only satisfied for $x>0$. You can take $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$ to obtain
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \big(x^2 f''(x) + xf'(x) + f(x) \big) = 1$$ 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \big(x^2 f''(x)\big) + 0\cdot f'(0) + f(0) = 1$$ 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \big(x^2 f''(x)\big) + f(0) = 1$$ 
It can be satisfied even with $f(0)=0$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f''(x) = \infty $. The argument that inserting $x=0$ to the eqaution gives you $f(0)=1$ is invalid, because it assumes that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f''(x)$ is finite, which (as you can check from the solution) is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=e^{t}$ in the given d.e. and you will get $$y''(t)+y(t)=e^{2t} +1$$ 
Solve this linear differential equation with constant coefficients and you will have $y(t)=acos(t)+bsin(t)+\dfrac{e^{2t}}{5}+1$
then use the initial conditions to find $a$ and $b$ and then substitute $t=ln x$.

Comment: The initial conditions translate to conditions on values at $t=-\infty$, which is slightly impractical for the oscillating part.